# My CSS Code is empty on Chrome Dev when using express server

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I am trying to serve my static css files on an express server. Once I start up the server and go to the tools it shows my css file is linked, but the code is not showing within the code editor. It seems Express is not serving the code it self. I am at a loss for why its not serving.

```js
/* App.js */
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const contactRouter = require('./routes/contact');
const timeRouter = require('./routes/time');

var app = express();




app.use('/contact.html/', contactRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/time.html/', timeRouter);

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get('*',(req,res) => { 
  res.sendStatus(404);
})



module.exports = app;



/* index.js */ 


var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.use(express.static('public'));

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('/Users/AugustShah 1/Documents/Coding-Tools/Projects/portfolio/portfolio/html-files/index.html');
});

router.get('/contact.html/',  (req,res,next) => {
  res.sendFile('/Users/AugustShah 1/Documents/Coding-Tools/Projects/portfolio/portfolio/html-files/contact.html');
  console.log('this works');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:
in my html file I was linking to my Public folder then stylesheets ../public/stylesheets/styl.css and the path just needed to be stylesheets/style.css

Comment: I would have ask you to pay attention to the css relative paths. As it fixed fine.

Comment: I am very new to Express and still trying to work out it out. I am trying to serve my HTML files in the same way by just using html-files/"insert HTML file name" (HTML files are in a folder called html-files) and I am getting a GET error. The reason I did not put them in the public folder is if I understand its that if I wanted to for example make a post request to a form in a static file then it wouldn't submit the form, or do I have that wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You wrote above that your problem has been fixed. If you have a new problem, you have to ask a new question.